# What is the Page Object Pattern in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: design-patterns, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

What is page object pattern in Selenium WebDriver?

What is the use of it and how can we use this in Selenium WebDriver?

Example will be appreciated.

Comment: A perfectly valid question. Doesn't make sense to close it. Reopen it to actually have more productive answers.

Comment: @Deep Indeed, the question does not ask for a ressource but for an explanation and should be reopened. On the other hand it seems not (re)searched at all so the quality is not very high.

Comment: @Trilarion That's a valid point about "not having done enough (re)search"..

Comment: Follow single responsibility principle while designing your page objects - You will have a well readable and reliable tests - more info: http://testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments

Comment: When looking for a definition of anything dev-related I always go for SO. I feel like the definitions/explanations on dev-blogs or in official documentations aren't generally very good. Way too lengthy, making it sometimes hard to distinguish what is important.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The documentation has already covered this. If you have any specific questions, feel free to edit your main post.

**Official:**

- [Page Objects](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) and [PageFactory](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) on Selenuim Wiki.
- [Page Object Design Pattern](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) on Selenium official site.

**Unofficial:**
Do a Google search, you will get a lot info on this.

- [Page Object Pattern](http://assertselenium.com/automation-design-practices/page-object-pattern/)
- [Page Objects in Selenium 2.0](http://blog.activelylazy.co.uk/2011/07/09/page-objects-in-selenium-2-0/)
- [Selenium 2/WebDriver Quick Tips: Page Object Navigation Strategies](http://www.wakaleo.com/blog/selenium-2-webdriver-quick-tips-page-object-navigation-strategies)
- [PageObject](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) by Martin Fowler

Answer (score 3):

[Edited to respond to the reply below.  And thanks, I'll do better.]

The purpose of the page object pattern is to completely encapsulate the testing interface to the web page.  This follows the time-honored practice of data hiding.

Here's the [Selenium article about the page object](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).

And here's my post ["Keep Your Page Objects DRY"](http://burdettelamar.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/keep-your-page-objects-dry/).