# What is the best approach to store URL strings for automated testing?

Tags: c#, selenium

For the past few months I have been developing a test automation package for a web application using Selenium in C#.

In some of the tests I need to verify the driver arrived at the expected URL. So far I have been storing the expected URLs in a .resx file, but I was told this is not a very good approach.

I'm pretty new to programming so I'm sorry if this seems trivial.

**Edit:**

Just to clarify I'm looking for an approach to **store** the URLs. I don't want them hard-coded but I don't think a .resx file is a very good option either.

Comment: Why do you need to store the URL's?

Comment: The application I'm testing is under early development so the the URLs still sometimes change

Comment: Either way, stored or hard coded into the page objects, you would still need to edit them manually. I don't see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Page Object Pattern](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) and have the URLs for the pages as a `const string` within the page object. That is the way I have been doing it in my Selenium tests.

Some more useful information in the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094238/what-is-the-page-object-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver)

You could expose the constant url through a static method on the page object, and then use that to do your assertation against the web drivers current url.

**EDIT:** Based on the comments above, it seems your concern is having one source of truth for the URLs

You could have a static URL factory, like so:

```
public static class UrlFactory
{
    public static string URL1 { get{return "www.url.com";}}
    //repeat as necessary
}
```

Then when you are setting up your page objects, the URL could be passed in the constructor by calling `UrlFactory.Url1` and this could assign its value to a private field within the page. Then when you are testing, you would call the same for your assertation like so:

`Assert.AreEqual(UrlFactory.Url1, _webDriver.Url)`

Comment: That's a great suggestion! I am using POP so I have no idea why I didn't think about this in the first place. Unfortunately it doesn't really answer my question. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @orm225 I've added an extra line to my answer about how to expose these URL's for your assertations. If the url you are trying to assert against is not one within your application that you have created a page for, I think resources or excpected result strings within the tests is the only way to do it.

Comment: It's not execrably what I was searching for but you were defiantly very helpful.

Comment: I've added some more information to help with your testing and construction of the page objects. I hope this has really helped @orm225

Answer (score 0):

I previously stored this kind of information (when using TestComplete) in an excel file. I kid you not.

My reason was because it was easy to share input vs output with my client.