# Identifying an element developed using ANgularJS in selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have an element developed using angular JS. Below are the information available when i inspect the element. I used the

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("workstation-opconsultant-icon workstation-icon")
```

to identify the element. But selenium not able to identify the element. please suggest how to identify the element.

```
<div _ngcontent-tby-c4="" class="homepage-tile"><div _ngcontent-tby-c4="" class="workstation-opconsultant-icon workstation-icon"></div><span _ngcontent-tby-c4="" class="font-bold homepage-tile-text text-white">OP Clinic</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`workstation-opconsultant-icon` and `workstation-icon` are actually two classes. You can do

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("workstation-opconsultant-icon")
# or
driver.find_element_by_class_name("workstation-icon")
```

If you want to locate by both classes use `css_selector` or `xpath`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".workstation-opconsultant-icon.workstation-icon")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='workstation-opconsultant-icon workstation-icon']")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried the below and it is working. driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".workstation-opconsultant-icon.workstation-icon").  Is there any way to dynamically get the object property in case of change in value in near future

Comment: I mean if the value used in css selected is changed, what to do?

Comment: @Pattabi Do you mean something like class `workstation-opconsultant-icon` changes to `new-class-name`?

Comment: @Pattabi You will have to update the locator. I suggest you learn about [POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094238/what-is-the-page-object-pattern-in-selenium-webdriver) if you aren't using it already, it will reduce your maintenance to minimum.